# Warning C6102 - VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, initialization, analyzer

Visual Studio 2013 offers an interesting static code analysis. Here's a warning I get that I can't get rid of:

> ```
> C6102     Using 'Attributes' from failed function call at line '1031'
>
> 'Attributes' is not initialized           1031
>  Skip this branch, (assume '<branch condition>' is false)         1031
> 'Attributes' is used, but may not have been initialized           1037.
> ```

The code is simple:

```
BOOL    GetDeviceVersionNumber(int Index, PUSHORT version)
{
/*
This function returns TRUE is it succeeds
and puts Version number in VersionNumber
*/
HANDLE h = GetHandleByIndex(Index);
if (!h || h==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return FALSE;

HIDD_ATTRIBUTES Attributes;
if (!HidD_GetAttributes(h, &Attributes))
{
    CloseHandle(h);
    return FALSE;
};

*version = Attributes.VersionNumber;
CloseHandle(h);

return TRUE;
}
```

Now, Attributes is not a pointer, it is a struct.
I did try to initialize it but this does not help.

Any idea?
Tx

Comment: Have you seen https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d2d7fb49-bfff-4963-9bc1-4ca2248fc401/code-analyzer-warning-c6102?forum=vcgeneral ?

Comment: @Veve Yes, I have. The question you refer to has a missing condition while in my case I pass a pointer to a structure.

Answer (score 1):

The first member of `HIDD_ATTRIBUTES` is `size` , that needs to be set to 
`sizeof(HIDD_ATTRIBUTES)` before its used in any calls, Windows uses it to 
figure out the version you are using.

Comment: You are quite right. This field should have been initialized. However, initializing it like this:
`Attributes.Size = sizeof(HIDD_ATTRIBUTES);`
did not solve the problem.